# Forecasting validation loss flactuation

Tags: validation, keras, lstm, forecast

I have a question for those who have some experience with timeseries forecasting.

I have been experiment with this field for few weeks and i was trying to forecast some timeseries with both ARIMA and LSTM models to compare the results.

Basically i did plot this graph Figure 1 that has 4 plots :

Top left : ARIMA training data points and fitted model points.

Top right : ARIMA test and forecast points.

Bottom Left : LSTM training data and fitted data (i could not really find fitted point for LSTM so i just forecasted the training data but you can just ignore that part).

Bottom right : Test and forecast data for the LSTM model.

This graph was acceptable and also i did compute the RMSE and MSE and LSTM gave lower error which agrees with most literature online that states the superiority of LSTM over ARIMA models.

However after i did plot the loss and validation loss of the LSTM model to have more insights, i noticed that the validation_loss is following a wierd flectuating pattern Figure 2.

I can explain this as follow : the time series has a lot of outliers or abnormal behaviour, so splitting it to train/validation/test would mean validation cannot be really a good metric to show how good the model can learn.

But since all research papers never show this graph and explain this problem, i don't have a solid argument to defende this idea.

what do you guys think?

Thank you in advance

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf,plot_pacf
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score,mean_squared_error,mean_absolute_percentage_error,mean_absolute_percentage_error
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import STL
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from scipy import stats
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
import statsmodels
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
import pmdarima as pm
register_matplotlib_converters()
import warnings
import time
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from numpy import array
import keras_tuner as kt
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from numpy import array

from tensorflow import keras
import keras_tuner as kt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
import random as rn
np.random.seed(123)
rn.seed(123)
tf.random.set_seed(123)
tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(123)

keras.utils.set_random_seed(123)

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


df3 = pd.read_csv('favorita_train.csv')

## 1 - Get TS and do STL 

print("TS lenbgth : "+str(len(df3)))
results = seasonal_decompose(df3['unit_sales'],period=30)
results.plot();


train_all = df3.iloc[:int(len(df3)*0.8)]
train = df3.iloc[:int(len(df3)*0.6)]
val = df3.iloc[int(len(df3)*0.6):int(len(df3)*0.8)]
test = df3.iloc[int(len(df3)*0.8):]


scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(train_all)
scaled_all = scaler.transform(df3)
scaled_train = scaler.transform(train)
scaled_train_all = scaler.transform(train_all)
scaled_val = scaler.transform(val)
scaled_test = scaler.transform(test)

# We do the same thing, but now instead for 12 months
n_features = 1
n_input =5
train_generator_all = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train_all, scaled_train_all, length=n_input, batch_size=1,shuffle=True)
train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train, scaled_train, length=n_input, batch_size=1,shuffle=True)
val_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_val, scaled_val, length=n_input, batch_size=1,shuffle=True)


adfPValue = adfuller(scaled_all)
adfPValue=adfPValue[1]
adi = len(scaled_all)/((scaled_all != 0).sum())
sd=scaled_all.std()
mean=scaled_all.mean()
cv2 = np.square(sd/mean)

print("CV2 (describe magnitude of demande variability <0.5 is good) :"+str(cv2))
print("SD (-2,2 is good | mean data variance  is low) :"+str(sd))
print("ADI (1.3 or smaller means smooth ts) :"+str(adi))
print("Stationarity test (stationary if <0.05) :"+str(adfPValue))


def model_builder(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    hp_units = hp.Int('units', min_value=1, max_value=50, step=1)
    hp_layers = hp.Int('layers', min_value=1, max_value=3, step=1)

    
    if hp_layers==1 :
        model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(hp_units,activation='relu'), input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
    elif hp_layers==2:
        model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(hp_units, activation='relu', return_sequences=True), input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
        model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(hp_units, activation='relu')))
    else: 
        model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(hp_units, activation='relu', return_sequences=True), input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
        for i in range(hp_layers-2):
            model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(hp_units, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)))
        model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(hp_units, activation='relu')))
            
    model.add(Dense(1))
    
    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])

    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),  loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

tuner = kt.Hyperband(model_builder,
                     objective='val_loss',
                     max_epochs=300,
                     factor=3,
                     directory='499',
                     project_name='949',
                     seed=123)

stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=30)

tuner.search(train_generator, epochs=300, validation_data=val_generator, shuffle=True, callbacks=[stop_early], batch_size=len(train_generator))
best_hps=tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]


print(best_hps.get('units'))
print(best_hps.get('layers'))
print(best_hps.get('window'))
print(best_hps.get('learning_rate'))


best_hps=tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]

model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)
history = model.fit(img_train, label_train, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2)

val_acc_per_epoch = history.history['val_accuracy']
best_epoch = val_acc_per_epoch.index(max(val_acc_per_epoch)) + 1
print('Best epoch: %d' % (best_epoch,))
```

[image]

[image]